# What's the analogous function for aasign() of R in Python?

Tags: python, r, variable-assignment, assign

There's a list.

```
stud = ['mark', 'kael', 'joey', 'ash']
```

I want to assign a dataframe to each of the items in stud list. (making each item in list as a variable name)
for eg.

```
mark = dataframe1
kael = dataframe2
joey = dataframe3
ash = dataframe4
```

I know we can do this in R using assign() function. how can we achieve this in Python.

Comment: by datafrane here do you mean Pandas dataframe ??

Comment: Note that this is possible in R, but there is usually no reason whatsoever to actually do this.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `exec()` to assign variable names from strings.
Something like this:

```
dataframe1,dataframe2,dataframe3,dataframe4 = {'a'},{'b'},{'c'},{'d'}
stud = ['mark', 'kael', 'joey', 'ash']
dfs = [dataframe1,dataframe2,dataframe3,dataframe4]

for v,d in zip(stud,dfs):
    exec('{}={}'.format(v,d))

>>> mark
{'a'}
```

Using DataFrame you have to change `dfs` from a list of objects to a list of strings:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import numpy as np

dataframe1,dataframe2,dataframe3,dataframe4 = DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 5)),DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 5)),DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 5)),DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 5))

stud = ['mark', 'kael', 'joey', 'ash']
dfs = ['dataframe1','dataframe2','dataframe3','dataframe4']

for v,d in zip(stud,dfs):
    exec('{}={}'.format(v,d))
```

Comment: {'a'} is a set and i want to give a dataframe. If I pass dataframes in **dfs**, it gives me a syntax error.

Comment: Then pass the name of the dataframe as string in dfs `dfs = ['dataframe1','dataframe2','dataframe3','dataframe4']`